# How how can i frame cut between, using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, frame

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "select='if(gt(scene,0.03),st(1,t),lte(t-ld(1),4))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -an trimmed2.mp4
```

my code but, it did not work for my case. help pls

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to trim from 1.25 seconds in to 5 seconds in:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1.25 -i in.mp4 -to 5 -an trimmed2.mp4
```

Same thing but specifying duration instead of end point (preferred probably):

```
ffmpeg -ss 1.25 -i in.mp4 -t 3.75 -an trimmed2.mp4
```

Or if you only wanted exactly 40 frames:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1.25 -i in.mp4 -frames:v 40 -an trimmed2.mp4
```

More info on seeking / trimming here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Cuttingsmallsections

Comment: What I want to do is not this. in the picture, what I want. :(

Comment: Thanks
this may be, but my video is 5-10 minutes. Too many jobs :( I need a practical code.